# How do I resolve "Error: "helm template" requires at least 1 argument"?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run `helm command` in the Jenkinsfile pipeline and I am getting an error that it is expecting at least 1 argument. Below is the code:

```
stage ('Create and Deploy to k8s Dev Environment') {
            //agent {label 'docker-maven-slave'}
            options {
                skipDefaultCheckout()
            }
            steps {                    
                    command """
                        echo "hiiiiiiii"
                        helm template -f portal-chart/values-dev.yaml --set image.tag=${IMAGE} | \
                        kubectl apply --server=https://dddd.gggg.com:443 --token='${DEV_NS_TOKEN}' --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true -f -
                    """
```

}

Below are the logs:

```
+ echo hiiiiiiii
hiiiiiiii
+ helm template -f portal-chart/values-dev.yaml --set image.tag=bde8ac5
+ kubectl apply --server=https://dddd.gggg.com:443 --token=eyjsfkjdhfkjdhfkjdhfkjhfdjhfjdfjZCI6IlI5Zi1YOFpnd2NzcUpUR1czTG45aUhwR2dHMkYx --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true -f -
Error: "helm template" requires at least 1 argument

Usage:  helm template [NAME] [CHART] [flags]
error: no objects passed to apply
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Please verify my `helm command` and let me know if I am missing something over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the `Chart`parameter.

```
helm template --help
   Usage:
     helm template [NAME] [CHART] [flags]
```

In your case it should be

```
 helm template -f portal-chart/values-dev.yaml --set image.tag=${IMAGE} portal-chart
```

`-f` only specifies the values file! You also must specify for which chart it should be applied on.

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much for your time. I was placing the `portal-chart` after the `-f`.